# ejecutar funcion mientras se escribe en JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo que cambiar el dibujo de un fondo (tengo una etiqueta cuyo style pueden ser 3 imágenes).

Concretamente es el calculo de IMC, tengo un INPUT en el cual tengo que escribir su peso (la altura ya la tengo).

Lo que no se es como hacer que **conforme escriba** su peso, sin darle a intro ni nada, vaya ejecutando una funcion para calcular su imc y segun su valor que cambie **en tiempo real** el fondo.

Comment: Cuéntanos qué has probado para que podamos ayudarte e inclúyelo en tu pregunta.

Comment: no he probado nada por que no se por donde cojerlo, realmente solo necesito saber el como hacer que cada vez que escriba un caracter ejecute una funcion, el resto se hacerlo (el calculo del imc, obtener el valor del input, cambiar el css...)

Comment: Por favor revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y un [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y demuestrale con esto a la comunidad que eres parte de las personas que buscan ayudar a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Podrías intentar utilizar la función onPress en un input de tipo texto... Pero si no lo intentas y nos muestras aunque sea cómo falla, no puedo ayudarte mucho más...

Comment: Gracias, al final usé keyup en vez de onPress... solo necesitaba saber el método para ya hacer el resto :P

Comment: Genial! Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

buscando un poco he encontrado el keyup, para que ejecute la funcion al soltar la tecla.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pesoIMC").keyup(function(){
    var texto_escrito = $(this).val();
    console.log(texto_escrito);
    // $("#un_div").html(texto_escrito);
})
})
```

la etiqueta html

```
<input placeholder="0" id="pesoIMC" type="input" class="pesoIMC ">
```

Comment: Toma en cuenta que recibes un string y que por tanto te puedes encontrar con valores no numéricos que te arrojen un error NaN. Valida primero antes de operar.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso!!